# How to add a small div not affecting middle align?

Tags: css, alignment

I have a layout with a middle aligned paging.

The paging is middle-aligned be this trick:

```
.pager_wrap
{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}
.pager 
{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}
```

This seems to be working fine.

But there was a request to add a facebook like button the right side of the pager, but NOT affecting the position and middle alignment of the paging.

I was thinking about somehow putting the facebook like in a div right after the .pager-wrap div, and somehow modifying its vertical alignment to be over the .pager-wrap div.

I'm no mage in css and these kind of problems tend to take extremely long time to figure out. Can someone help me out on this one?

[image: layout hell]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the facebook icon in a div, position it relatively, float to the right and if needed apply a z-index to bring it higher on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

```
.button  
{
     float: right;
     position: relative;
     right: 10%;
}
```

Comment: both solutions are the same, I'll toss a coin and accept one of it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `float` your can give `display:inline-block` to it's & text `text-align:center` to it's parent for `center your paging` DIV . May be you write like this:

```
.pager_wrap
{
    background:red;
    text-align:center;
}
.pager
{
    background:yellow;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline /*IE*/
    *zoom:1;
    text-align:right;
    padding:10px;
}
.facebook{
    float:right;
    width:30px;
    height:40px;
    background:blue;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/DdPtv/

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with this is that you actually move the centered part to the left by the half of the .facebook div's width. Try setting the .facebook's width to bigger values.